# TSQL count occurrences in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table where each column is a question and rows are answers that can assume value from 1 to 4

What is the most efficient way to calculate occurrences of each answer per question?

Input table

```
q1  q2  q3
1   3   1
2   1   4
1   2   1
```

Desired Output table

```
answer  q1  q2  q3

    1   2   0   2
    2   1   1   0
    3   0   1   0   
    4   0   0   1
```

So far I arrived to the following (for q3 question) but it is just for one question

```
CREATE TABLE #t
  (
    answer int
  )
insert into #t (answer) values (1)
insert into #t (answer) values (2)
insert into #t (answer) values (3)
insert into #t (answer) values (4)

select * into #q3 from (select q3 as q3,count(*) as occurenceq3
                    from [table]
                    group by q3) as x

select t.answer,tb.occurenceq3 as occurenceq3
from #t t left join #q3 tb on t.answer=tb.Q3

drop table #q3
drop table #t
```

Comment: Probably unpivot then pivot.

Answer (score 5):

```
select answer, q1, q2, q3
from
    q
    unpivot (answer for q in (q1, q2, q3)) as upvt
    pivot (count(q) for q in (q1, q2, q3)) as pvt
```

I made the mistake of first trying `count(*)` but I think it makes sense that the aggregation must be explicitly on the column being pivoted, even though I think they would be logically equivalent.

Comment: Maybe you can't reference a base table directory. I was trying to run this on SQL Fiddle but the site is acting weird as usual.

Comment: If you go back to your original posting and replace the count(*) with count(q), the query will work.

Comment: I haven't done a good job committing the syntax to memory unfortunately.

Comment: you are right Mat. I've just edited. Many thanks to both of you for the support. Any suggestion where I can study this stuff.

Comment: Technet has an article. This one might be better as an intro: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

Comment: Google search usually gives you a good starting point, but after that you've got to play around with it until it sticks and you 'get' it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:-

```
CREATE TABLE #question (q1 int, q2 int, q3 int)
INSERT INTO #question
VALUES
(1,3,1),
(2,1,4),
(1,2,1);

--unpivot to start with
WITH
UNPIVOTED AS
(
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT q1,q2,q3
    FROM #question) p
UNPIVOT
    (answer FOR question in (q1,q2,q3)) AS unpvt
)

--Then pivot
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT answer, question FROM unpivoted) p
PIVOT
(
COUNT(question)
FOR question IN (q1,q2,q3)
) as pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most efficient way, I would suggest putting an index on each of the "q" columns and running the query as:

```
select a.answer,
       (select count(*) from #question q where q.q1 = a.answer) as q1,
       (select count(*) from #question q where q.q2 = a.answer) as q2,
       (select count(*) from #question q where q.q3 = a.answer) as q3
from (select 1 as answer union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
     ) a;
```

This basically uses the indexes for counting the values and should be quite fast, faster than aggregating all the unpivoted results.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
select t1.dis,
q1=(select count(q1) from CountAnswers where q1=t1.dis), 
q2=(select count(q2) from countAnswers where q2=t1.dis), 
q3=(select count(q3) from countAnswers where q3=t1.dis) 
from (select dis from( select q1 as dis from CountAnswers union select q2 as dis from CountAnswers union select q3 as dis from CountAnswers)mytab)t1;
```